# Designing a Queue to be a shared memory

Tags: c, memory, posix, shared-memory

I'm attempting to design/implement a (circular) queue (in C) as a shared memory so that it can be shared between multiple threads/processes.

The queue structure is as follows:

```
typedef struct _q {
    int q_size;
    int q_front;
    int q_rear;
    int *q_data;
}queue;
```

Which supports the following functions:

```
int empty_q(queue *q);
int display_q(queue *q);
int create_q(queue **q, int size);
int delete_q(queue **q);
int enqueue(queue *q, int data);
int dequeue(queue *q, int *data);
```

As per the queue size mentioned by the user, the memory for q_data will be allocated in create_q().

Question: How to create a shared memory for this queue using system functions provided in "sys/shm.h"? Any code snippet/example for creating/attaching/retrieving/deleting shared memory for the queue data-structure using shmget(), shmat(), shmctl(), etc would be a great help.

Comment: If you want to communicate processes using a queue-like mechanism, wouldn't it be better to use [message queues](http://www.it.uom.gr/teaching/c_marshall/node25.html)? Across threads from the same process, a standard queue protected by a critical section would suffice

Comment: @dario_ramos message queues would be an ideal solution for this problem ..but I'm trying to give an example using a queue to find out how to attach a data-structure with a shared memory.

Comment: In that case, when I messed with Unix IPC, I followed [Beej's guide to Unix IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/). It even has some jokes! You can go directly to the [shared memory section](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/shm.html)

Comment: I added the last comment as an answer, since I checked the guide a bit and it has exactly what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I messed with Unix IPC, I followed [Beej's guide to Unix IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/). It even has some jokes! You can go directly to the [shared memory section](https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/split-wide/shm.html#shm). It has snippets explaining each step, and a full example at the end.

Comment: Beej's guide is awesome. Thanks for sharing. :)

Comment: I referred this also <http://kohala.com/start/unpv22e/unpv22e.chap12.pdf> .. relatively good info.

Comment: Looks like a more detailed reference, good for you. A little detail: Remove the "<" and ">" from your link, otherwise it won't work (I could see the doc because I edited the URL)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example that creates shared memory the size of a structure, writes some data to it and prints it out.  Run one instance and it will create the shared memory and put some "data" in it, and then wait for a key press.  Run a second instance in a different command prompt, and the second instance will print the contents of the memory.

```
typedef struct
   {
   char a[24];
   int i;
   int j;
   } somestruct;


void fillshm(int shmid) {
   somestruct *p;

   if ( (p = shmat (shmid, NULL, 0)) < 0 )
      {
      perror("shmat");
      exit(1);
      }

   printf("writing to shared memory\n");
   strcpy(p->a, "my shared memory");
   p->i = 123;
   p->j = 456;
}


void printshm(int shmid)
{
   somestruct *p;
   if ( (p = shmat (shmid, NULL, 0)) < 0 )
      {
      perror("shmat");
      exit(1);
      }

   printf( "%s, %d, %d\n", p->a, p->i, p->j );
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

   int shmid;

   // see if the memory exists and print it if so
   if ( (shmid = shmget (1234, 0, 0)) >= 0 )
      printshm( shmid );
   else
      {
      // didn't exist, so create it
      if ( (shmid = shmget (1234, sizeof( somestruct ), IPC_CREAT | 0600)) < 0 )
         {
         perror("shmget");
         exit(1);
         }

      printf( "shmid = %d\n", shmid );

      fillshm(shmid);
      printf( "Run another instance of this app to read the memory... (press a key): " );
      getchar();

      // delete it
      if ( shmctl (shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL) < 0 )
         {
         perror("semctl");
         exit(1);
         }
      }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. This is correct (but incomplete). Any idea on how to attach/associate a structure to a shared memory?

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj:  Assign the memory to a pointer to a structure.  Same as memory from a malloc call.  You need to make sure that each process has an identical definition of the structure (with the same packing).

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj: For fun, I updated the example to use a structure and to be slightly more interesting (allow two instances two run and have one fill the memory and the other to print it).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your code snippet gave me few good hints to complete my task. +1