# May I send pointers via pipes in the same process, is it safe?

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, pipe

For some reasons, I want to send pointers via pipe (certainly, not crossing processes)
E.g., some data should be recycled after everything done, the (pointer of the ) structure was send to recycling thread via a pipe; or I want to send some structure from one working thread to another. In the examples, no thread can wait.

So, may I send pointers via pipes?

Think about following things:

1. I write 8 bytes (a pointer, for example) to a pipe with O_NONBLOCK. but its buffer had only 7 bytes left. Then '7' was returned from write() call. Then other threads might write anther 8 bytes after more buffer became available. When the reader thread read the pipe, it would get an invalid pointer. Segment Fault.
2. I send only pointers to this pipe. I've read some articles about pipe, and I noticed that when I write or read 8 bytes it's an atomic operation. Is it confirmed that (buffer size of a pipe % sizeof(void*)) == 0 (or at least on an x86_64 linux)? If so, will condition(1) happen?

It will be quicker and easier to send pointers directly. But if it is not safe, I will have to encode the pointers such as what UTF-8 does, or think about other ways.

Thanks a lot~

Comment: I've found that's ok. Thanks to everyone. man 7 pipe: 
O_NONBLOCK enabled, n <= PIPE_BUF
              If there is room to write n bytes to the pipe, then write(2)
              succeeds immediately, writing all n bytes; otherwise write(2)
              fails, with errno set to EAGAIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pipes, writes smaller than the value of the macro `PIPE_BUF` are guaranteed to be atomic, i.e. they cannot be split up in the way you are concered about. So your idea is safe.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you ensure that you are receiving 8 bytes before casting your buffer to a pointer, I don't see what is *technically* wrong with this. There's no point in doing any encoding.

However, there are certainly other, better ways of communicating pointers between threads. Note that using a pipe requires a system call (transition to kernel-mode) for each `read` and `write`.

For example, implement a queue in shared memory:

- [Designing a Queue to be a shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8478802/119527)

A [`futex(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) will allow you to implement fast user-space locking (the definition of a futex!) around your data structures.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good way. But I'm using epoll on the pipe :)

Comment: One other thing to check: the address must still be valid when the value read is used.  You can't go freeing the memory after you write the address to the pipe and expect to use it safely.